# com.apple.ManagedSettingsAgent was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, permissions, screen-time

I'm trying to use Screen Time API and lock specific apps. I have requested permission like this:
[image]

But I'm getting the following error

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem and ask permission for locking apps using Screen Time API?

Answer (score 0):

Signing & Capabilites Add Family Controls
[image]